# How can I create iframe/embeddable content from my WordPress site?

Tags: embed, iframe

I have a Google map on my site that I use to plot out various points of interest as it relates back to my blog. I have had a few people suggest to me to create an embeddable version of the map so they can embed it on their sites too.

All of the data from my map is stored away in some custom post types that I fetch with an GET request in some custom jQuery code.

Would I need to create a plugin or a Widget? What's the best approach for creating something like this?

Comment: a block, shortcode, widget, etc the same way you would put any arbitrary code inside a post or pages content. Which of those is the correct one depends enormously on the context though and the tools you intend to use it with. E.g. an answer that recommends the future block based systems would be useless if your site is built with Visual Composer or other shortcode based page builders

Comment: @TomJNowell a block, shortcode or widget would all be specific to my site, though, correct? I am looking at creating something that could be embedded on other sites from my site.

Comment: Ah then OEmbed is where you should investigate, specifically the WP post OEmbed filters, the same ones that let you embed a WP post. You can filter their HTML etc, though I don't remember the specifics